# How to use parameter or variable or output of compose action as tracked properties in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

How can we use parameter or variable or output of compose as Tracked properties?

We need to use a value from HTTP request payload as tracked properties. We are able to fetch required value using Xpath. We are not able to use it as tracked properties. We are thinking to use either parameter or variable or output of compose. So, How can we use parameter or variable or output of compose as Tracked properties?

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes I have used below xml as my HTTP body.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<produce>
  <item>
    <name>Gala</name>
    <type>apple</type>
    <count>20</count>
  </item>
```

Below is the flow of my Logic app.

[image]

The tracked property expression that worked for me is as below.

```
"@base64ToString(xpath(xml(triggerBody()),'/produce/item/name')[0]['$content'])"
```

[image]

Tracked property that I'm receiving in my log analytics workspace.

[image]

Comment: Hi Swetha, images are not loading. Could you please write expressions in words?

Comment: @SumantKumarMandal I have added the expression in the answer using which I could get the output